# How do I retrieve the value of a javascript promise in java/nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, scala, nashorn

I'm trying to execute some javascript code in scala using the nashorn/ScriptEngine pattern, the javascript function i'm calling returns a promise and let's assume I have no agency over this return type.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn")

val resp: ScriptObjectMirror = engine.eval("Promise.resolve([1,2,3])")
```

I can't seem to figure out any way in which I can retrieve the internal value, instead I am returned this blackbox `ScriptObjectMirror`. All I really want is to pull out the internal value, i.e. in javascript it would look like

```
Promise.resolve([1,2,3]).then(function(result) {
    // do something with the result
}
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the outer engine context has no idea that it should wait for the Promise to finish.